# tmux shell aborted and linux shell is behaving weird

Tags: linux, shell, vim, tmux

I have been hitting tmux aborting issues once in few days.

Symptoms:

- My tumx session has vim and other processes running for almost 4-5 days
- All of sudden it aborts without any error msg and I end up on a corrupted linux shell where every time I press enter I see shell name in the same line.

  ```
  testdb# testdb#
  ```

I tried killing tmux server socket and restarting it again , But no luck.

```
killall -s SIGUSR1 tmux
tmux attach
```

Comment: read formatting help and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 0):

To reset a broken terminal use:

```
$ reset
```